# Truth table using recursion

Tags: c#, recursion, truthtable

i am trying to create a truth table in c# for 3 symbols so it should produce 2^3 = 8 tables. but my recursive method is not working.

My code is below. in each loop i add a symbol and make new dictionary with one true and one false value.

```
    public void TTEntails()
    {
        Queue<string> s = new Queue<string>();
        s.Enqueue("p");
        s.Enqueue("q");
        s.Enqueue("r");
        TTCheckAll(s, new Dictionary<string, bool>());
    }


    public void TTCheckAll(Queue<string> symbol, Dictionary<string, bool> model)
    {
        if (symbol.Count == 0)
        {
            PLTrue(model);
        }
        else
        {
            string topSymbol = symbol.Dequeue();
            TTCheckAll(symbol, ReturnDict(model, topSymbol, true));
            TTCheckAll(symbol, ReturnDict(model, topSymbol, false));
        }
    }

    private Dictionary<string, bool> ReturnDict(Dictionary<string, bool> model, string key, bool value)
    {
        Dictionary<string, bool> newDict = new Dictionary<string, bool>(model);
        newDict.Add(key, value);
        return newDict;
    }
```

the result produced is as follows:

```
p, True
q, True
r, True


p, True
q, True
r, False


p, True
q, False


p, False
```

the result should be

```
p, True
q, True
r, True

p, True
q, True
r, false

p, True
q, false
r, True

p, True
q, false
r, false

p, false
q, True
r, True

p, false
q, True
r, false

p, false
q, false
r, True

p, false
q, false
r, false
```

Comment: And for those of us playing-at-home, what should the results look like

Comment: i have added the expected result. thanks

Comment: You forgot to add the definition of `PLTrue(model);`

Comment: i  am just printing the truth table in it for now. once i get the complete truth table ill proceed. thanks

Comment: Well, the results are exactly what I'd expect from that code. Have you tried step-by-step debugging? Either that recursion is not even close to what you are looking for or you got some data type wrong

Comment: i did changed the data type. instead of method TTCheckAll() was a bool and return was (TTCheckAll(true) && TTCheckAll(false)). but the result was the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a copy of a queue to each true/false branch:

```
public void TTCheckAll(Queue<string> symbol, Dictionary<string, bool> model)
{
    if (symbol.Count == 0)
    {
        PLTrue(model);
    }
    else
    {
        string topSymbol = symbol.Dequeue();
        TTCheckAll(new Queue<string>(symbol), ReturnDict(model, topSymbol, true));
        TTCheckAll(new Queue<string>(symbol), ReturnDict(model, topSymbol, false));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change with this.

```
 public void TTCheckAll(Queue<string> symbol, Dictionary<string, bool> model,bool value )
{
    if (symbol.Count == 0)
    {
        PLTrue(model);
    }
    else
    {
        string topSymbol = symbol.Dequeue();
        TTCheckAll(symbol, ReturnDict(model, topSymbol, value),(value?false:true));

    }
}
```

Comment: i tried it but it just produces 1 truth table not 8